# Lazy Instantiation not working iOS

Tags: ios, lazy-initialization

I've declared a property in the .h file called `cellTitles`. In my .m file, I have a method as follows:

```
-(NSArray *)cellTitles
{
    if(!_cellTitles){
        _cellTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"several strings", nil];
        NSLog(@"Home Array Created");
    }
    return _cellTitles;
}
```

But the `array` is not created when I refer to `_cellTitles` or `self.cellTitles`. I have several NSLogs that all say the array has 0 objects. Do I need more than this. Some answers have said I need to synthesize, but as I understand it, that is no longer necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to make the code more readable.

Comment: Can you show your property declaration, and show the code you're using to access the property?

Comment: As a guess, is _cellTitles already being created in the class constructor?

Comment: Good point, please show your class's `init` method as well.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint verifying that this code is called? Is your property declared as (nonatomic,strong)? –

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your property is assigned strongly.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cellTitles;
```

Comment: this is not right, you can have a weak property lazy loaded if you want

Comment: True, but in this case it doesnt seem like the any other object holds a strong reference to the array. Edited the answer.

Comment: Most of the time you want objects which have mutable subclasses to be `copy` .. just saying ;)